# Aggregating by date field

Tags: views, datetime

I've been trying to aggregate (SUM) by a date field with a custom format (YYYY, MM) but its not working as expected. I tried Views Date Format SQL and Merge rows modules but didn't work for me. Also, some other suggested solution is to group by field (Table settings) which also does not fit my needs.

```
2014-08-05     12
2014-08-05     15
2014-08-15     20
2014-09-09     10
```

Im trying to do it as follows:

```
2014,Aug      47    
2014,Sep      10
```

Note: My collected dates attributes are year, month , day (i.e. 2014-08-05 00:00:00)

Comment: are you trying to aggregate date by YEAR-MONTH ?

Comment: Yes, this is it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) module. It supports many useful aggregation functions. As an exmaple creating the following output:

```
Industry    Companies             Turnover
Food (2)    Heiny, McRonalds      $566,000,000
Clothing (1)Cenneton              $99,000,000
IT (2)      AcquiB, PreviousBest  $30,000,000
Totals              5             $695,000,000
```

From this source table:

```
Industry    Company Name    Turnover
IT          AquiB           $25,000,000
Clothing    Cenneton        $99,000,000
Food        Heiny           $66,000,000
IT          PreviousBest    $5,000,000
Food        McRonalds       $500,000,000
```

> With the grouping taking place on, say Industry, and aggregation
>   functions TALLY, ENUMERATE and SUM applied on Industry, Company Name
>   and Turnover respectively, the final result with a descending sort on
>   the last column will display like below. Note that the module
>   identified three groups. It also added a totals row, Views Calc style.

Comment: But, does it aggregate by date?

Comment: hmmm ... why wouldnt it?! It aggregates by `fields` if you can include a date field in your View then you can use this module. Nobody will do your homework/task/assignment for you. I'm simply providing information on a module that will likely make your life easier. Although, you may have to do some learning.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to do it for me tenken, i know pretty well how to aggregate fields and looking only for hints to do it for the date, my issue here is to aggregate date field which I believe has some things need to be taken into account (like format, granularity,.etc) in order to be aggregated properly. I also tried to create a custom field retrieving year, month but didn't work too. Thanks for your answer anyways

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to tell the database to chop a part of the field. So if your field column in the database is `field_date`, then you should have in the views query something like:

`GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(field_date, '%Y-%m')`

As there's no aggregation plugin (as far as I know), most probably you will need to alter the views query to add that part to the query (there's a hook for that). Also, make sure that `field_date` is not listed again there, as in that case, the `field_date` will kick out the other one.

The above example uses a `datatime` field type (by the database). If you storing the date as a string, you can cut the string end with another SQL function.